# what is the Proper way of testing axios functions in jest in this case?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, axios

I have written a basic test case to test my axios function. The test case is failing. I am trying to test an axios call which gets me a json. I format that data and resolve the Promise function.
The jest gives error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

`

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

```
  67 |                 'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
  68 |             },
> 69 |         }).then((response: any): any => {
     |           ^
  70 |             if (response.statusText === "OK") {
  71 |                 return Promise.resolve(response.data);
  72 |             }
```

`

**mocks**/axios.ts

```js
export default {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
    request: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
};
```

// libHelper.tsx

```js
export default class libHelper{
    constructor() {
        // parameters initialization
        }
    }

    public fetchMsGraph = (accessToken: string): Promise<GraphData> => {
        return axios.get(Constants.someURL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
            },
        }).then((response: any): any => {
            if (response.statusText === "OK") {
                return Promise.resolve(response.data);
            }
            else {
                return Promise.reject(Error(`API Response not OK`));
            }
        }).catch((err: any): any => Promise.reject(Error(`Fetch API Error ${err}`)));

    }
```

// libHelper-tests.tsx

```js
import libHelper from "../Scripts/libHelper";
import axios from "../__mocks__/axios";
import { UserDataGen1, Data } from "../Scripts/interfaces";

describe("", (): void => {

    test("basic test", () => {
        let msalobject: MsalHelper = new MsalHelper();
        expect(msalobject).toBeInstanceOf(MsalHelper);
    });

    test("not so basic", async () => {
        const resp: UserDataGen1 = {
            idp: "string",
            memberName: "string",
            lastName: "string",
            firstName: "string",
            cid: "string",
            authenticatedState: "string",
            picture: "string"
        }
        axios.get.mockImplementation(() => { Promise.resolve(resp); });

        let libObject: libHelper = new libHelper();
        const rand: Data = await libObject.fetchAPP("asd");

        expect(rand).toEqual(resp);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the axios mock?

Comment: What is `__mocks__/axios`?

Comment: Your initial problem was you were not "returning" the promise in this line `axios.get.mockImplementation(() => { Promise.resolve(resp); });`. Using `mockResolvedValue ` would avoid this kind of mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what made it pass

```
import mockAxios from "../__mocks__/axios";
const data: UserDataGen1 = {
            idp: "string",
            memberName: "string",
            lastName: "string",
            firstName: "string",
            cid: "string",
            authenticatedState: "string",
            picture: "string"
        }
    const resp: any = {
            data: data,
            status: 200,
            statusText: "OK",        
    }

    mockAxios.get.mockImplementation((url: string) =>{
                console.log(url);
                return Promise.resolve(resp);
            });
```

Comment: You should really use `mockResolvedValue` it is simpler and cleaner. And it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mockResolvedValue`:

```
       const resp: UserDataGen1 = {
            idp: "string",
            memberName: "string",
            lastName: "string",
            firstName: "string",
            cid: "string",
            authenticatedState: "string",
            picture: "string"
        }
        axios.get.mockResolvedValue(resp);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, now i am getting a new error
```typescript
TypeError: axios_1.default.get(...).then is not a function
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant `mockResolvedValue`. I have updated the code.